# ClassNotFoundException when running IBM code example

Tags: java, lotus-notes, lotus-domino

I'll eventually have write some custom data in my notes documents. But before that I wanted to see how it works, so I've copied/pasted the example from IBM Knowledge Center about replace/getItemValueCustomData in two seperated agent.

Problem is that when I try to read the custom data, the Read Agent throw that exception :

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: customData.IntIntString
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:291)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.resolveClass(ObjectInputStream.java:619)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNonProxyDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1609)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readClassDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1514)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1768)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1347)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:364)
    at lotus.domino.local.Document.getItemValueCustomData(Unknown Source)
    at JavaAgent.NotesMain(JavaAgent.java:14)
    at lotus.domino.AgentBase.runNotes(Unknown Source)
    at lotus.domino.NotesThread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Here is the code :

Write agent :

```
import customData.IntIntString;
import lotus.domino.*;

public class JavaAgent extends AgentBase {

    public void NotesMain() {

        try {
            Session session = getSession();
            AgentContext agentContext = session.getAgentContext();

            IntIntString iis = new IntIntString();
            iis.setData(1, 2, "String1");

            Document doc = agentContext.getDocumentContext();
            doc.replaceItemValueCustomData("IntIntStringItem", "IntIntStringType", iis);
            doc.save();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Read agent :

```
import intIntString.IntIntString;
import lotus.domino.*;

public class JavaAgent extends AgentBase {

    public void NotesMain() {

        try {
            Session session = getSession();
            AgentContext agentContext = session.getAgentContext();

            Document doc = agentContext.getDocumentContext();
            if (doc.hasItem("IntIntStringItem")) {
                IntIntString iis = (IntIntString) doc.getItemValueCustomData("IntIntStringItem", "IntIntStringType");
                iis.show();
            } else {
                System.out.println("No item IntIntStringItem in document");
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

IntIntString class :

```
package customData;

import java.io.Serializable;

public class IntIntString implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 6875473472063311349L;

    private int int1;
    private int int2;
    private String string1;

    public void setData(int i1, int i2, String s1) {
        int1 = i1;
        int2 = i2;
        string1 = s1;
    }

    public void show() {
        System.out.println("Int1 = " + int1);
        System.out.println("Int2 = " + int2);
        System.out.println("String1 = " + string1);
    }
}
```

Bytes wrotes by the Agent :

```
.  I  n  t  I  n  t  S  t  r  i  n  g  T  y  p  e  .  .  .
10 49 6E 74 49 6E 74 53 74 72 69 6E 67 54 79 70 65 AC ED 00 
.  s  r  .  .  c  u  s  t  o  m  D  a  t  a  .  I  n  t  I
05 73 72 00 17 63 75 73 74 6F 6D 44 61 74 61 2E 49 6E 74 49 
n  t  S  t  r  i  n  g  _  j  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  I
6E 74 53 74 72 69 6E 67 5F 6A 96 B1 EC F4 8D F5 02 00 03 49 
.  .  i  n  t  1  I  .  .  i  n  t  2  L  .  .  s  t  r  i
00 04 69 6E 74 31 49 00 04 69 6E 74 32 4C 00 07 73 74 72 69 
n  g  1  t  .  .  L  j  a  v  a  /  l  a  n  g  /  S  t  r
6E 67 31 74 00 12 4C 6A 61 76 61 2F 6C 61 6E 67 2F 53 74 72
i  n  g  ;  x  p  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  t  .  .  S  t  r
69 6E 67 3B 78 70 00 00 00 01 00 00 00 02 74 00 07 53 74 72 
i  n  g  1
69 6E 67 31
```

Do I miss something or is IBM drunk?

Link to the examples : [replaceItemValueCustomData method](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSVRGU_9.0.1/com.ibm.designer.domino.main.doc/H_EXAMPLES_REPLACEITEMVALUECUSTOMDATA_METHOD_DOC_JAVA.html), [getItemValueCustomData method](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSVRGU_9.0.1/com.ibm.designer.domino.main.doc/H_EXAMPLES_GETITEMVALUECUSTOMDATA_METHOD_JAVA.html).

---

Edit : Tried to define the "IntIntString" class in the "Agent" class, but that did not work, nor put the class in a .jar and import it.

---

Edit 2 : As suggested in comments, I tried to declare the class public in the agent. For some reason when I tried that I had to implements Serializable in the agent, which I did. Still got the same exception.

Then I tried to declare it public in a separate file (because public classes need their own file) in the "customData" package, but that didn't work either.

Also tried to read the field when the document is open in read mode. I got that exception and the field erased (saw that from document property) :

```
NotesException: Supplied Data type name does not match stored CustomData type
    at lotus.domino.local.Document.NgetItemValueCustomData(Native Method)
    at lotus.domino.local.Document.getItemValueCustomData(Unknown Source)
    at JavaAgent.NotesMain(JavaAgent.java:14)
    at lotus.domino.AgentBase.runNotes(Unknown Source)
    at lotus.domino.NotesThread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Seams that the field is not read/write correctly, Data type should match.

Code updated.

Comment: Question is not clear. What is the problem? What are you doing to solve it and where are you stuck?

Comment: As I said at the fifth line of the question, the problem is that the code example provided by IBM is throwing exception.

Comment: It means "IntIntString" class is not defined/found. I don't know about "IBM drunk", but you should import that class directly into your project or maybe IBM have a jar file about all of these classes, you can import that. I think you should look "IntIntString.class" search from Google.

Comment: @pilkington The "IntIntString" class is defined in the same file as the agent. I don't get why it would not be found.

Comment: @Jouramie You're right, I saw that class now. Could you try to define IntIntString class in Agent class?

Comment: @pilkington Just tried it, but I got the same exception. Also tried to pack the class into a .jar and import it, but that didn't worked either.

Comment: A bit of a guess, but the IniIntString class probably needs to be public. Otherwise, I don't see how it could be resolved from inside the Document.getItemValueCustomData method.

Comment: @RichardSchwartz Tried that and edited post.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Create a jar file from custom class IntIntString

```
import java.io.Serializable;

// Define custom data
public class IntIntString implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    int int1;
    int int2;
    String string1;

    public void setData(int i1, int i2, String s1) {
        int1 = i1;
        int2 = i2;
        string1 = s1;
    }

    public void show() {
        System.out.println("Int1 = " + int1);
        System.out.println("Int2 = " + int2);
        System.out.println("String1 = " + string1);
    }
}
```

and put the jar file into folder

- **domino/jvm/lib/ext** (Domino Server - for backend and runOnServer agents)
- **notes/jvm/lib/ext** (Notes Client - for agents started on client side)

This way, ObjectInputStream can find the custom class IntIntString as it is globally available in agent's JVM. This is the missing piece in IBM's documentation of replaceItemValueCustomData/getItemValueCustomData.

Comment: It worked, thanks alot. This really need to be added to the documentation.

Comment: I voted this answer up because it sounds right to me.  I think it should resolve the problem.  On the other hand, it might not be the best long term solution.  It can be difficult to manage a jar in jvm/lib/ext.  For example, how do you make sure you have the same version of the jar on all Domino servers?  Personally, I would avoid the problem in the first place.  Rather than serialize the Java object (replaceItemValueCustomData) I would find a different way to store the data (JSON, XML, separate Notes items?).

Comment: I'll probably store the data in separate Notes items and create fonction rebuild my objects. Anyways half of the data where already store this way because I needed them in a view. That's still not the answer I wanted to ear but it solve the problem.

Comment: @Dave: I agree absolutely. I wouldn't use ...CustomData in production. It's even worse if client side agents using it. Then you have to make sure that this jar is available on every Notes client... Probably this inconvenience is the reason why very little can be found on internet about this functions.

Comment: That's actually what I had in mind when I suggested putting the class in a .jar file.  Unfortunately I couldn't test it to be sure.

Answer (score 2):

Here's what I did...

1. Created a Java agent called WriteAgent
2. Under Src->(default package), created a new class called IntIntString.java
3. Pasted in your code as is
4. Again under Src->(default package), created a new class called JavaAgent.java
5. Pasted in your WriteAgent class without the import to customData;

Compiled and ran without error and updated the document.

Comment: Maybe I didn't specified it in the question but the Exception is thrown by the Read Agent. Just added it.

Comment: Try as I might, I can only get the same result you do.  As far as I can tell it's not my agent that can't find the class it's the Document class that's failing when you call the getItemValueCustomData().  It worked with a boring basic type (I tried Integer.)  I don't have the means here to test but I wonder if you put your custom class into a .jar (instead of a script library) whether that would work?

Comment: I tried to import the .jar directly in the agent, but I still get the same exception. I'll see if I can import the class file instead.

Comment: Also, when I move the "IntIntString" class from the customData package to the defaut package, the Document class seems to keep searching it in the customData file, even when I clean/build all. Looks like there is a refresh problem somewhere.